# No error logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log [nginx]

Tags: python, nginx, flask, error-logging, error-log

The nginx on my Google Linux server is not printing error logs in the file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. The content of my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app` file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user_name/app/app.sock;
    }
}
```

I am using python-flask. Till now, I have been using logging module of python to log data but obviously I had to figure out the problem. When viewing `/var/log/nginx/` folder, I can see various `error.log` and `access.log` files. I deleted the `error.log` to check whether it is created again or not. It was created again but still doesn't have any logs of the `500 Server errors`. By the way if it helps, I followed [this](https://github.com/Julian-Nash/simple-flask-demo) guide to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) directive by your own, for example in `server {}` context:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user_name/app/app.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app` to `server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user_name/app/app.sock;
    }
}` but still no logs. I even tried changing the location. The file is being created at the new place but no logs are being saved there.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Had to thoroughly check it @user973254

Comment: @Blake please show output of following command: `nginx -T`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/H3WMcESN This was the output @user973254

Comment: @Blake I see that you have `default_server` in this block `server { server_name _; }`, you can remove it if you don't need it, because it can intercept with some queries going to your actual `server {}` block with `uwsgi_pass ... `. `error_log` present, at least it should report when nginx starts/restarts/stops, try to add `warn` log level in `http {}` context like this `error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log warn;`, then restart nginx and see what happens.

Comment: Not a single log. I checked my file but the only code which BARELY could have affected it is this https://pastebin.com/9DtUMQve . I have no idea what is going wrong. Is the nginx automatically redirecting my output somewhere or what?